# Can an action that updates the store be dispatched on componentDidUpdate()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

According to [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) componentDidUpdate() is the place where to cause side effects but this.setState() should be avoided (or handled with caution) since it causes an extra rendering. **What about dispatching an action that updates the store?** Will the same *terms* apply for this scenario as well?

I haven't found any documentation on this, what I've found is [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43764637/8840456) but its purpose for dispatching an action is actually to fetch data from server.

Comment: I have faced a problem by dispatching an action in componentDidMount() causes an infinite loop and hangs the UI, did you face this issue too?

Comment: @HaiderAli, compentDidMount doesn't cause infinite loop,  It does with componentDidUpdate when using setState unless you have some condition to update the state

Comment: i think you are misplacing `componentDidMount` with `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: That is correct, fixed

Answer (score 1):

> According to React's documentation [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is the place where to cause side effects but this.setState() should be avoided

There is nothing in the docs that says that.
On top of that it clearly says:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount()

I think you mixed it up with [componentdidupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> What about dispatching an action that updates the store

It is perfectly fine to do that in `componentDidMount`, if the store's update will cause a new `prop` to get injected to the component, another `render` call will take place. and that is perfectly fine!

Remember, `componentDidMount` is called only once ine the lifetime of a component:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree)

So no way to get an infinite loop there (like suggested in comments).

Again, i think you were referring to `componentdidupdate` which will get invoked on each update. so updating the state there will cause it to run again and again.
This is why you should update the state conditionally:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition

**Edit**

> What about dispatching an action that updates the store

Same rule applies here. dispatching an action could trigger another render if new prop values are passed. this can lead to an infinite loop.
As mentioned in the docs, just check a condition before dispatching the action.

Comment: I indeed missplaced componentDidMount for componentDidUpdate

Comment: Do you need another clarification regarding `componentDidUpdate` and using conditions before dispatching actions or setting the state?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your action:

1. If action leads to immediate rerender, you probably have something wrong with app architecture.
2. If action updates the store but doen't do rerender on this exact component or does fetch some information via ajax and cause rerender then, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general that's fine. However, if the action dispatched updates the props passed to your component, it might re-render; so I would handle it with caution in this case (same as you would do with `setState`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dispatch an action in componentDidMount() then think about the re-render, I have faced this issue in my React Native app, where I dispatched an action in componentDidMount() and it causes useless re-renders.
You can put your dispatch either in

```
if(!isFetching){
}
```

or in setTimeout because it will contain the dispatch to run only once

```
setTimeout(() => {

    }, 200)
```